# Can I recover the tags of my question before they were edited?

Tags: support, tags, editing, retagging

I would like to improve the tagging of my questions as I see that the tags are edited many times. Is there a way of comparing the new tags with the original tags without keeping a record of the original tags?

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/431/759

Answer (score 4):

Look at the edit history by clicking on the time-stamp listed next to the most recent edit, or by going to http:// [meta.] judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/ [post ID number] /revisions.

For this post, the revision history is at https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1073/revisions where you can see the tags I added at 2012-05-06 10:30:35Z SST (StackExchange Standard Time).